# SQL Select inside Select using an existing column as reference,

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table that looks like this.

```
| ItemCode | AvgPrice | PriceList | ComplimentaryItemCode |
| AL01     | 22       | 1         | AL02                  |
| AL02     | 19       | 1         | AL03                  | 
| AL03     |  7       | 1         | AL01                  |
| BA01     | 50       | 1         | NULL                  |
| BA01     | 60       | 1         | BA01                  |
```

I want to create an extra column in a query to show me the AvgPrice of the ComplimentaryItemCode, like this;

```
| ItemCode | AvgPrice | PriceList | ComplimentaryItemCode | AvgPriceComplimentary
| AL01     | 22       | 1         | AL02                  |   19 
| AL02     | 19       | 1         | AL03                  |    7
| AL03     |  7       | 1         | AL01                  |   22
| BA01     | 50       | 1         | NULL                  | null
| BA01     | 60       | 1         | BA01                  |   50
```

So far I tried this, but no luck;

```
SELECT     a.ItemCode, a.AvgPrice,  t.PriceList,  a.ComplimentaryItemCode,
                          (SELECT     AvgPrice
                            FROM          MATERIALS AS a
                            WHERE      (ItemCode = ComplimentaryItemCode)) AS AvgPriceComplimentary
FROM         MATERIALS AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      PRICES AS t ON t.ItemCode = a.ItemCode AND t.PriceList = 1
WHERE     (T.PriceList <> 107) AND (T.PriceList <> 108)
```

Any help would be wonderful!

Answer (score 1):

You should use window functions for this:

```
SELECT m.ItemCode, m.AvgPrice, p.PriceList, m.ComplimentaryItemCode,
       AVG(AvgPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY ComplimentaryItemCode)  as AvgPriceComplimentary
FROM MATERIALS m LEFT OUTER JOIN
     PRICES p ON t.ItemCode = m.ItemCode AND t.PriceList = 1
WHERE p.PriceList NOT IN (107, 108) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `top 1` and using different aliases for the table in the correlated subquery:

```
select 
    a.ItemCode
  , a.AvgPrice
  , t.PriceList
  , a.ComplimentaryItemCode
  , (
   select top 1 AvgPrice
   from MATERIALS as i
   where (i.ItemCode = a.ComplimentaryItemCode)
   ) as AvgPriceComplimentary
from MATERIALS as a
  left join PRICES as t 
    on t.ItemCode = a.ItemCode 
   and t.PriceList = 1    /* if t.PriceList = 1, why the following where? */
where T.PriceList <> 107
  and T.PriceList <> 108
```